# There is no voltage on the field of the alternator

Tags: avionics, cessna-152

I’m having a problem with a Cessna 152, the alternator do not increase the voltage of the system, just like “stay” i already try to change the regulator and the alternador and is the same, also when i check the voltage on the “F” (field) terminal, there is 0 volts, but when the wires are not attached on the alternator i have the 24+ Volts in there, any one use to have a problem like this? I’ve been trying all that i can but there isnt success, please if other avionics could help me it will be greate!

Comment: Have you asked a qualified mechanic to evaluate the alternator? Troubleshooting balky equipment is often far easier in person than over the internet.

Comment: Could be a short. Ask a mechanic.